# How to link my commits to my github account, without showing emailadress in commit?

Tags: git, github

I have a question: I recently made my personal github account to make some open-source projects. As a test, I created a dotfiles repo. From my machine, where the global properties point to my work github account, I have made some commits. That made my work remail show up in the public repo, which I didn't want. With rebasing and force pushing I solved that issue. I have rebased the author to my correct username of my personal github account, but left my email blank, because I also dont want to have my personal email show up. However, now the author of the commits has the right username, but it does not link to my account. This leads to my question:

How do I config git to use my personal github account, so it links correctly, without showing any emailadress in any commit?

Can I just config git so my user.email is my personal email, but can I count on it not showing up online?

Comment: GitHub uses the email address to link, so if you specifically remove this from the commits, GitHub won't link them. Nothing to be done about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody else pointed me to this help page:
https://help.github.com/articles/about-commit-email-addresses/

Which explains that you can have your personal emailadress hidden from all commits. If you want to hide your email, check the correct setting in github. This will give you a no-reply emailadress from github, which you can configure to use in any git repo via the typical git config user.email "email@domain.com". Also, any changes made in the online github webpage will also use this no-reply emailadress.

This is the solution to keep your personal emailadress private for pulic repo's.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure your email per repo, for example:

```
git config user.email "email@example.com"
```

Check more about it in this article: [Setting your email address for a single repository](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git/#setting-your-email-address-for-a-single-repository)